# faster updating of peakpowerforchannel

Tags: iphone, microphone

I am using NSTimer to update peak power from iphone. From monitoring, it does not update very fast. I need high frequency of updating peak power in order of 100 micro second (100us). I also try with usleep(100) to update every 100us. Still very slow. Can someone help me to point out how to achieve this? I am thinking I need to use this code to measure distance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you capture the audio (record, input, or file), access its samples from the pcm cbr (uncompressed, with a fixed sampling rate) stream, and read the samples of the range you are interested in. considering the high frequency, you will only have to analyze a small number of samples (2-5, depending on the sampling rate). you may need to interpolate to improve accuracy with so few samples.

Comment: Thank you. To be able to read from pcm cbr stream that you mentioned, Does that means I have to study "Audio Queues Buffer and AudioQueueLevelMeterState" in order to get faster sampling?

Comment: AudioQueue is one possible approach. to read the input samples, you access them from the `mAudioData` field of the `AudioQueueBufferRef` passed to your `AudioQueueInputCallback` function. the level meter state is unlikely to provide the granularity you require. so you just read the input samples you are interested in from the `mAudioData` field. to approximate distance based on a frequency, you'll need to know the sampling rate of the input samples, have some sync reference, and determine the io latency of the iostreams. audio queues require high-ish latency (cont)

Comment: (cont) so you may need to drop down to lower level CoreAudio apis to achieve the lowest latency io -- if that's a concern.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and try to figure out how to do that. Thank you again.

Comment: you're welcome. a naive implementation would simply scan the max absolute value of the samples in the range. for such short periods, you may have 'too much' error if you don't interpolate where necessary. AudioQueue should have some sample code for you to get started with.